# Unable to navigate localhost:8080 on jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I had done the setup of jenkins and it was running fine.

Even i had run my script successfully.

But after restarting my system when I enter "localhost:8080"
It shows me"

**This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.**

Comment: Check your firewall settings.

Comment: I have tried after disabling firewall,Still facing same issue

Comment: Are you sure it restarted OK? Process exists? Checked logs for errors, "Jenkins is up and running" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if Jenkins is up and running. Propably you did not active it to start on boot.

On Linux check if jenkins is running by:

```
$ sudo systemctl status jenkins
● jenkins.service - LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/jenkins; generated)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2020-06-25 12:07:05 CEST; 1 weeks 4 days ag
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 0B
   CGroup: /system.slice/jenkins.service
```

If the status in `Active` is not `active` you can start the Jenkins service via

```
sudo systemctl start jenkins
```

On Windows you can check if the Jenkins service is running by:

```
sc query "Jenkins"
```

If it doe snot show "RUNNING" you can start it via

```
net start jenkins
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have Restarted the machine, Jenkins is stopped running.
So you have to run the Jenkins.
For that You have to go to **run** window and then navigate to the folder where **Jenkins.war** is placed and then execute the **"java -jar jenkins.war"** command.

Then go to localhost:8080

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sO3g2.png)